# Conditionally replace all values based on value of 1 column in R

Tags: r, conditional-formatting

**Background**

The data set is given below for reproducibility

```
data <- structure(list(rest1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
               rest2 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
               rest3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
               rest4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               rest5 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
               rest6 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The output is given below:

```
A tibble: 10 x 6
   rest1 rest2 rest3 rest4 rest5 rest6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 2     1     0     0     0     1     0
 3     0     1     0     0     0     1
 4     1     0     0     0     0     0
 5     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1     1     0
 7     0     1     0     0     0     1
 8     1     0     1     0     1     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     1
10     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

**My question**

Based on the values of column sleep 6, there needs to be changes made. Given the variable `rest6` is equal to 1, the other variables `rest1-rest5` need to be changed to 0. Here, variables 3 and 7 need to be fixed.

The *desired* output is below:

```
  rest1 rest2 rest3 rest4 rest5 rest6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 2     1     0     0     0     1     0
 3     0     0     0     0     0     1
 4     1     0     0     0     0     0
 5     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1     1     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     1
 8     1     0     1     0     1     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     1
10     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

**Previous Attempts**

I have attempted to do so using my basic knowledge of *R*. My logic is if `rest6` is equal to 1 and the observations are equal to 1, then set to 0, else we return the original value. However, this has not worked and I am a little unsure/not as proficient in *R* as of deliberate.

```
data <- ifelse(data$rest6 == 1 & data[,c(2:5) == 1], 
               0, 
               data[,c(2:6)])
```

Another attempt I have tried to use a `function()` to identify where to place the values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `data[-6] <- data[-6] * !data[, 6]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple base R solution may be to isolate all those in which `rest6 == 1` and change all values in the relevant columns to 0:

```
data[data$rest6 %in% 1, 1:5] <- 0
```

Output:

```
  rest1 rest2 rest3 rest4 rest5 rest6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 2     1     0     0     0     1     0
 3     0     0     0     0     0     1
 4     1     0     0     0     0     0
 5     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1     1     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     1
 8     1     0     1     0     1     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     1
10     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse`, a simple solution would be to  loop `across` columns rest1 to rest5, and use `case_when` to replace the values that correspond to 1 in rest6 to 0

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(rest1:rest5,
    ~  case_when(rest6 == 1 ~  0, TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   rest1 rest2 rest3 rest4 rest5 rest6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 2     1     0     0     0     1     0
 3     0     0     0     0     0     1
 4     1     0     0     0     0     0
 5     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1     1     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     1
 8     1     0     1     0     1     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     1
10     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[rest6 == 1, 1:5 := 0]
```